# Reading inputs from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable, which has comboboxes and text fields. I want to have a save button, which saves all the data from the jtable into an arraylist. I've found some examples but they were all unhelpful. The Table is using the defaultTableModel. How do I read the inputs after the push of the save button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DefaultTableModel#getValueAt(col, row)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29), if you want to read each cell individually...

[`DefaultTableModel#getDataVector()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#getDataVector%28%29), which returns a `Vector` of `Vector`s, where the outter is the rows and the inner are the columns, if you want to process the rows/columns in some speical way...

Comment: The thing is, then it gives me an arrayoutofboundsexception 0>=0. I don't know what I am doing wrong, even though I searched for it.

Comment: What gives you an array out of bounds?  Have you checked the results of `getRowCount` and `getColumnCount` to make sure there's data in the model...

Comment: I solved it. It was because I declared the table twice when initializing. So when getValueAt() was called, the table was empty. @MadProgrammer your answer was totally right. My problem was somethin gelse. getValueAt works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: @user2751040, `MadProgrammer your answer was totally right.` and yet you haven't accepted the answer, which is the standard way to close a question and you find the answer.

Comment: @camickr, sorry i'm new to asking questions in stackoverflow.